# Chat Widget Php

Tags: php, yii, chat, livechat

I need to embed chat in my website. There are many third party chat widgets available in php but they have their own logo there. I want to keep my website to its scope no display of 3rd party usage. For this reason I was wondering there is open source php chat widget that can be integrated in PHP.

I have seen but both show their owner info or refer to their website. I do not want that

[Bumpin](http://www.bumpin.com/)

[Chatango](http://chatango.com)

Comment: If you just need to implement something like a chat room, why not roll your own with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bit.ly/wPVuxH  This should suffice, the first link.

http://blogupstairs.com/8-free-open-source-chat-application-based-ajax/ Try some of those.